# Get View and ViewModel to communicate using a common Protocol

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm trying to tell the View that it needs to navigate to ether one of the two destinations using the LiveData:

```
class IntroFragment : Fragment()
{
    private lateinit var introViewModel : IntroViewModel

    override fun onCreateView( inflater : LayoutInflater,
                               container : ViewGroup?,
                               savedInstanceState : Bundle?): View? 
    {
        introViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of( this ).get( IntroViewModel::class.java )
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_Intro, container, false )
    }

    override

    fun onViewCreated( view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle? )
    {
        introViewModel.navigateToSection1.observe(this, Observer {
            Navigation.findNavController( view ).navigate( R.id.action_showSection1 )
        });

        introViewModel.navigateToSection2.observe(this, Observer {
            Navigation.findNavController( view ).navigate( R.id.action_showSection2 )
        });
    }
}
```

IntroViewModel:

```
class IntroViewModel : ViewModel()
{
    private val _navigateToSection1 = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val navigateToNotificationSettings: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _navigateToSection1

    private val _navigateToSection2 = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val navigateToSection2: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _navigateToSection2

    init
    {
        _navigateToSection1 = true
    }
}
```

The problem is that I would need to give at least 5 commands from the ViewModel to View. One of the solutions I was thinking is to define an interface:

```
interface IntroProtocol
{
    fun navigateToSection1()
    fun navigateToSection2()
}
```

And then pass the interfaces method as an argument back to the view like this:

IntroViewModel:

```
class IntroViewModel : ViewModel()
{
    private val _navigateTo = MutableLiveData<IntroProtocol>()
    val navigateTo: LiveData<IntroProtocol>
        get() = _navigateTo

    init
    {
        _navigateTo = IntroProtocol.navigateToSection1() // I get "Unresolved reference navigateToSection1"
    }
}
```

And then I could implement the same IntroProtocol in the View like this:

```
class IntroFragment : Fragment(), IntroProtocol
{
    private lateinit var introViewModel : IntroViewModel

    override fun onCreateView( inflater           : LayoutInflater,
                               container          : ViewGroup?,
                               savedInstanceState : Bundle?         ): View?
    {
        introViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of( this ).get( IntroViewModel::class.java )
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_Intro, container, false )
    }


    override fun onViewCreated( view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle? )
    {
        introViewModel.navigateTo.observe( this, Observer {
            callLocalMethodByName( this ) // not sure how call the local method by name dynamically
        });
    }


    override fun navigateToSection1()
    {
        Navigation.findNavController( view ).navigate( R.id.action_showSection1 )
    }


    override fun navigateToSection2()
    {
        Navigation.findNavController( view ).navigate( R.id.action_showSection2 )
    }
}
```

But I don't understand how to do this and if it's even possible. The reason I want to pass the interfaces method is because it would be very convenient to have a single clean definition/protocol of which methods the ViewModel knows it can call on the view and the view would inherit them which would result in nice structure. Is this possible? If not, what would be an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you dont need the Interface, but to give your MutableLiveData a value, you need to do it like this:

```
_navigateToSection1.value = true
```